# Como ler <br/> em arquivos HTML e imprimir como quebra de linha?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Fiz um web scraper utilizando os módulos `BeautifulSoup` e `requests`, que pega a definição e exemplo de conceitos no Urban Dictionary. Este é código, utilizando a palavra "reparation" como exemplo.

```py
word = 'reparation'
r = requests.get("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term={}".format(word))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='html.parser')
definition = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "meaning"}).text
example = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "example"}).text
```

O programa retorna o exemplo do site como:

> "Bob: Here is $50 for me hitting you.Charles: Thanks for the reparation."

Porém, há duas quebras de linha no site, deixando o exemplo como:

> "Bob: Here is $50 for me hitting you.
>
> Charles: Thanks for the reparation."

Como faço para incorporar essas quebras na string `example`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como `text` retorna o texto sem as tags, o `<br>` também é removido.

Então o jeito seria substituir as tags `<br>` antes de obter o `text`:

```py
# obtém a tag (e não o text)
example = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "example"})
# substitui os br que tem dentro da tag
for br in example.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")

# agora sim pega o texto
print(example.text)
```

Com isso eu troco cada `br` por uma quebra de linha (`\n`), e a saída será:

```
Bob: Here is $50 for me hitting you.

Charles: Thanks for the reparation.
```

---

Ou, em vez de substituir a tag, podemos adicionar a quebra de linha nela:

```py
for br in example.find_all("br"):
    br.append("\n") # usar append em vez de replace_with

print(example.text)
```

A diferença é que agora as tags `br` terão como conteúdo a quebra de linha (`\n`), e quando chamarmos `text`, ele removerá as tags mas manterá o `\n`.

Vale lembrar que [tanto o MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) quanto o [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) definem que a tag `br` não tem conteúdo. Embora o WHATWG defina que na verdade o conteúdo do `br` é um ["*Nothing content model*"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing), que por sua vez só pode ter um [*inter-element whitespace*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#inter-element-whitespace) (que por sua vez, é definido como um ou mais [*ASCII whitespaces*](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace), que no caso podem ser espaços, TAB's e quebras de linha - ou seja, o `\n` seria um conteúdo válido para a tag `br`, por isso tanto o `append` quanto o `replace_with` seriam soluções válidas).